# Applying a function to a list using '<='

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary

I am trying to apply a function to a list to identify all instances where the temperature is less than 22 degrees. I want to apply this function to a row of an SQLite database. I have tried to use the map function, but this returns the result `<map object at 0x100783240>`rather than a list with 1s.

Here is the input I'm practising with before connecting to the SQLite database:

```
temperature = [13, 20, 36, 34, 23, 28, 34, 35, 20]
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
def non_wear_function(x):
    nonwear = []
    if temperature <= 22:
        nonwear.append(1)
        return nonwear

print(map(non_wear_function, temperature))
```

When I tried to print the nonwear list like this:

```
Print(nonwear)
```

it gave the error

```
Name error: non wear function not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to read the basics of the language a tad more extensively before asking here: you can convert any iterator like `map` to a list using `list`. This solves your initial problem.

The second problem occurs because you don't take scope into account (also see [this](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_global_vs_local_variables.php)).

If you want to do what I understand (i.e. get a `bool` array indicating where `temperature` is at most 22), the `non_wear_function` will not help you: it either returns `[1]` or `None`. Instead you might want to use a structure as below:

```py
def non_wear_function(t):
    return (t <= 22)

print(list(map(non_wear_function, temperature)))
```

Although in this circumstance, the use of either lambda functions or comprehensions might be better suited:

```py
print([(t <= 22) for t in temperature])
print(list(map(lambda t: (t <= 22), temperature)))
```

**EDIT**

If you'd like to, you can also convert `bool` to `int` using the `int` function, e.g.:

```py
print([int(t <= 22) for t in temperature])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried to use list(map(non_wear_function, temperature)), but this gives the error TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: That's because `temperature` is a list, you want to compare it to `x`, which is the individual element you're supplying.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this method seems to work. I have 2 further questions: what makes using the lambda function preferable? And is there a way to convert the 'none' to '0' because I want to sum the list afterwards.

Comment: `lambda` is often used for short in-line functions because they don't require all of the lines for a function. I'd say list comprehension is best in this specific case. There are ways to convert `None` to `0` (e.g. comprehension, loops), but I'd just suggest returning `int(t <= 22)` from your function instead, or adding `return 0` at the end of your function. This way, `None` is never actually added to your list in the first place, and you're saved the costs of finding them a second time.